# Bootstrap 3 media queries don't work beyond sm

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, media

Whatever I do, I can't seem to get the media queries to work properly.

So I have in my html a certain div class="check"

And in my css:

```
.check{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

    @media(min-width: 768px){ 

    .check{
    background-color: red;
    }

};

 @media (min-width: 992px){  
    .check{
    background-color: blue;
    }

};

@media (min-width: 1200px){ 

    .check{
    background-color: brown;
    }

};
```

The result is: xs: yellow ; sm: red  ; md: red; lg: red

---

If I do:

```
@media(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px){ same }
@media(min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1200px){ same }
@media (min-width: 1200px){ same }
```

I get: xs: yellow ; sm: red  ; md: yellow; lg: yellow

What am I doing wrong? How can I get it to work properly?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: I want to get    xs: yellow ; sm: red ; md: blue; lg: brown

Comment: The example that you have posted in your question works exactly as you describe, here's live [demo](https://jsbin.com/mosujo/edit?css,output)

Comment: halfzebra, thank you very much. the demo works indeed. I got what my mistake was: the semicolons I had in the code. You made me understand that there was no mistake where I thought I had so I had to look for the mistake elsewhere. Thank you.